# Read the stderr of a process using PTRACE(2)

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls, ptrace

Hi dear Stackoverflowers :),

In the past weeks I have been diving into the *obscure* (at least to me) world of the ptrace system call. My goal is **to read the stderr** of a different process. For debugging purposes it could be a child process, but in production I would like to read any (root privileges required  I guess).

My understanding says that I have to follow the following flow:

1. **PTRACE_ATTACH**
2. **PTRACE_SYSCALL** to get notified the next time the tracee triggers a syscall,
3. **waitpid** syscall to be able to access to the data.
4. **PTRACE_GETREGS** to understand whether it is a **write** syscall and if it's writing to fd number 2.
5. **PTRACE_PEEKDATA** to read what has been writtento fd number 2.

Could someone help me on validating if I am right or not. And then understanding how to implement the right steps?

This would be of great help.

My sources so far have been:

```
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html
https://groogroot.eu/the-ptrace-system-call/ (really good tutorial)
https://keithtech.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/how-to-use-ptrace_getregs/
https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~paullu/C498/meng.ptrace.slides.pdf
https://github.com/eklitzke/ptrace-call-userspace
https://eklitzke.org/ptrace
```

Update:

I have been able to read the data that the process is dumping into the std err. My goal now is to fully understand how it works. As soon as it is ready, then this question will be followed by my own answer.

Working example can be seen in: [Mittcher Glove Github repo](https://github.com/failtale/mittcher-glove)